# Are the first 3 DVDs of Debian enough for a offline install and use?

Tags: linux, debian, installation

I have a computer that will never get in touch with the internet and want to install Debian on it. Are the first 3 DVDs of Debian enough for a offline install and use or do I need all 16 DVDs?

Answer (score 3):

That depends on the packages you need.
From personal experience when installing Linux, I rarely needed more than the
first two DVDs.

Below are some excepts from the FAQ.

[Which of the numerous images should I download? Do I need all of them?](https://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#which-cd):

> The packages are sorted by popularity: The first CD/DVD/BD contains the installation system and the most popular packages. The second one contains slightly less popular ones, the third one even less popular ones, etc. You will probably only need the first couple of DVDs (or the first few CDs) unless you have very special requirements.

For special requirements, the answer is in
[Which CD/DVD/BD image contains package XYZ?](https://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#search-for-package)

> To find out which image contains a certain file, use the
>   [cdimage search tool](https://cdimage-search.debian.org/).
>   It has knowledge of just about all the Debian CDs/DVDs/BDs produced by Debian since the Woody release, covering all the official releases (both older archived releases and the current stable release) and the current sets of daily and weekly testing builds.